# Вызов метода getPrefernces внутри класса ViewHolder в классе RVAdapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-shared-preferences

https://pastebin.com/fMGdXNYF
Меня попросили реализовать SharedPrefernces в классе
Дело в том что хоть я и могу обьявить обьект класса SharedPreferences (sPref)
но когда я пытаюсь создать метод и в нем написать : sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
андроид просто не видит сам getPreferensec

```
class RVadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVadapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Constructor> foodList;
//public static SharedPreferences sPref;

public RVadapter(Context context, List<Constructor> foodList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.foodList = foodList;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //FoodConstructor foodConstructor = foodList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(foodList.get(position).getSectionTitle());
    holder.description.setText(foodList.get(position).getSectionDesc());
    holder.price.setText(foodList.get(position).getPrice());
    Picasso.get().load(foodList.get(position).getSectionImage()).into(holder.image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";

    public SharedPreferences sPref;
    TextView title;
    ImageView image;
    TextView description;
    TextView price;
    View btnPlus;
    View btnMinus;
    TextView txtCount;
    int count;



    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        btnMinus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus_butt);
        btnPlus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus_butt);
        txtCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnMinus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                count += 1;
                if(count > 0){
                    txtCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                    btnMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    count += 1;
                    txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                }

            }
        });

        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                count -= 1;
                if (count == 0) {
                    count = 0;
                    txtCount.setClickable(false);
                    btnMinus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    txtCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                txtCount.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            }
        });
//            public void saveText(){
//                sPref 
//            }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Как проявляется то, что "андроид просто не видит сам getPreferen**sec**"?

Comment: попробуйте вызвать его на контексте вот так context.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: если context не поможет, измените передаваемый тип с Context на Application - точно сработает. p.s. хотя и на Context должно заработать.

Comment: Да, если вызываешь getPreferensec не внутри активити, то делай это через контекст. А вообще работа с шаредпреференс, внутри адаптера, и тем боле внутри ViewHolder - плохая идея. Лучше что бы это выполнялось где то в отдельном классе, а в конструктор адаптера прокинуть интерфейс с методом saveText()